# MySQL query to get value that is not assigned multiple times

Tags: mysql

So I have a table that consist of a `campaign_id` and a `post_id`.
A `campaign_id` can have multiple `post_id`.
But a `post_id` can only be assigned to **one** `campaign_id`.

Eg:
This is valid

```
campaign_id | post_id
100           1
100           2
100           3
```

This is not valid

```
campaign_id | post_id
100           1
100           2
100           3
101           1 <-- `post_id` assigned to 2 `campaign_id`
```

I'm trying to write a query that will return the number of campaigns assigned per `post_id`, so I can do some sanity check, but couldn't figure out how.

Something I have now:

```
select distinct campaign_id, post_id from table
where post_id is not null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, using GROUP BY and COUNT aggregate:

```
SELECT t.post_id
     , COUNT(DISTINCT t.campaign_id)
  FROM mytable t
 GROUP BY t.post_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.campaign_id) > 1
 ORDER BY t.post_id
```

NOTES:

The `HAVING` clause can be omitted, if you want to return all values of `post_id`, including those that are associated with only one `campaign_id`.

The `DISTINCT` keyword could also be omitted. That would have an influence if there are duplicate values of `campaign_id` for a given `post_id`. For example, with these rows:

```
campaign_id   post_id
-----------   -------- 
100           1
100           1
100           1
```

whether you want a count returned as 1 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `COUNT`:

```
SELECT COUNT(campaign_id)
 FROM table
 GROUP BY post_id
 WHERE post_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: group by will not work because it'll group the different campaign_id into 1 row.